# Randomly set position of imageView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a random generator and in each case I am trying to change the position my UIImageView.

My code does not work as it just keeps its original position that is set on the storyboard.

Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)myButton {

    int RandomImageChange = arc4random() % 3;
    switch (RandomImageChange) {
        case 0:
        {
            [self.myImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(35,85,52,52)];
        }
        break;

       case 1:
        {
             [self.myImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(321,125,52,52)];
        }
        break;

        case 2:
        {
            [self.myImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(202,45,52,52)];
        }
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated, thank you

Comment: where is the function being called? in view didload? at runtime? when?

Comment: By the action of a button @Larcerax

Comment: perfect, thanks, and one sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be due to a large number of reasons. Here are a couple of options:

- Your IBOutlet isn't connected to the actual image on the .xib file or storyboard and therefore isn't really pointing to it (you can check if it's nil).
- You have autoLayout 'on' and therefore can't set the frames manually.

Hopefully, one of these options will solve you're problem. Good Luck!

Comment: Your first bullet point is wrong: the documentation states that *arc4random() seeds itself on a regular basis from the kernel strong random number subsystem...*

Comment: Perfect! It was because Auto Layout was on! Thanks a lot @Chonch

Comment: @Nerrolken, you're right. I edited the original response. Thanks.